# Pop up/ Msgbox if user create same name in dash plotly

Tags: python, sql, plotly-dash

I m trying to create a msgbox in Dash plotly if a user try to enter the same datain a dataframe.

Example :

| Name | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | row1 |
| test4 | row |
| test1 | row |

==> Pop up while saving the third line : Attention ! the name already exist in the dataframe, please try another.

I didn't find any information about this topic.. pop up with condition if. Can you help me please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dialog box that is normally hidden that contains the text you want. Add a callback that listens to the table, and have that callback's logic check for existing values. The output for the callback should be the style for the dialog box, which it sets from hidden to visible when the table has duplicate values.

Edit: Example of a hidden div:

```py
html.Div(
    id='my-hidden-div',
    style=dict(display='none'),
    children=[
        # whatever child elements you want here
    ]
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you give me an example of a hidden div ? thank you

Comment: Yes, I added an example.